# disabled works in IE but not in firefox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, cross-browser

this is my javascript code. on load function i have to disable btndelete ..it works correct in iE but in firefox, buton is not dsabled..i dont know is this a css issue or what?

**Javascript**

```
 window.onload = body_Onload;

            function body_Onload()
            {
                    var btnDelete = document.getElementById('<%=btnDelete.ClientID%>');
                btnDelete.disabled = true;
            }
```

**HTML**

```
<asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" CssClass="cssbutton" Text="Delete" Width="60px" OnClick="btnDelete_Click" />
```

**CSS**

```
.cssbutton
{
    font-weight: bold;  
    border-right: #3C8FD1 1px solid;
    border-top: #3C8FD1 1px solid;
    border-left: #3C8FD1 1px solid;
    border-bottom: #3C8FD1 1px solid;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #045FA7;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-image: url(../App_Images/cssbuttonbg.gif);
    line-height: 14px;
}
```

**HTML Generated Code**

```
<input type="submit" name="pageMain$contentPlaceHolderMain$btnDelete" 
    value="Delete" onclick="return btnDelete_Click();"
    id="contentPlaceHolderMain_btnDelete" class="cssbutton" style="width:60px;"/>
```

Comment: How does the generated HTML of the button look like?

Comment: <input type="submit" name="pageMain$contentPlaceHolderMain$btnDelete" value="Delete" onclick="return btnDelete_Click();" id="contentPlaceHolderMain_btnDelete" class="cssbutton" style="width:60px;" />

Comment: @Nikhil - Sorry, tested in FF and verified not working. Got IE confused with FF.

Comment: @Nikhil - I added that code you posted to your question. Remember, you can always click [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10765149/edit) below your question to add more details there if they're not really fit for a comment :)

Comment: I guess someone should ask if you're sure that property is getting called... have you put an alert or a console.info statement by the disabled property call? If not, I'd suggest starting there to rule that out as a possible issue.

Comment: Ya i have taken alert it always fire

Comment: Good to know! Thanks. I also don't see where `btnDelete_Click();` is defined? Is that an ASP thing or is that code missing from the question?

Comment: btnDelete_Click() doesnt matter for our issue.. Its ASP thing

Comment: What does the generated Javascript function look like? Specifically, what does this line look like in the page: `var btnDelete = document.getElementById('<%=btnDelete.ClientID%>');`

Comment: var  btnDelete = document.getElementById('contentPlaceHolderMain_btnDelete');

Comment: Have you checked it is *actually* disabled? Firefox doesn't grey out buttons, it simply disables them. Can you still click the button?

Comment: I added a style in the JavaScript/css that makes the FireFox look like IE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example page I made, based on your question and the information in the comments:

This works in both IE and FireFox. The difference is, in IE the button is greyed out when disabled. In FireFox, the button looks the same, but is disabled.  So you may want to assign a class to it and style that greyed out for FireFox.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script>
function body_Onload()
{
    var btnDelete = document.getElementById('contentPlaceHolderMain_btnDelete');
        btnDelete.disabled = true;
        btnDelete.className += ' btndisabled';
}
</script>
<style>
.cssbutton
{
    font-weight: bold;  
    border-right: #3C8FD1 1px solid;
    border-top: #3C8FD1 1px solid;
    border-left: #3C8FD1 1px solid;
    border-bottom: #3C8FD1 1px solid;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #045FA7;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-image: url(../App_Images/cssbuttonbg.gif);
    line-height: 14px;
}
.btndisabled 
{
    background-color: rgb(236,233,216);
    color: #CCC;
    font-style:normal;
}
</style>
</head>
<body onload="body_Onload();">
<form>
<input type="submit" name="pageMain$contentPlaceHolderMain$btnDelete" 
    value="Delete" onclick="return btnDelete_Click();"
    id="contentPlaceHolderMain_btnDelete" class="cssbutton" style="width:60px;"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```